# Faster to query one binary(1) field or 8 bit fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

If I have 8 boolean values in a record and those 8 values are always used when doing a query against the table and the data in the table is static (read-only), is it faster to get matching records by indexing and querying against a one byte field like binary(1) or is it better to have 8 separate bit columns with all 8 added to an index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes on single bit field will be basically useless. A bit has terrible selectivity, 0 or 1, and will be likely disregarded by the optimizer. 8 indexes on 8 bit fields are going to be 8 indexes disregarded by the optimizer.

An index on a byte column is only slightly more selective, with 256 distinct values. But if you are seeking individual bit patterns, like 'is bit 3 on', then there are no way to express this as a individual value to seek nor as a range.

Conclusion is that no matter what you try, you will end up with a table scan *anyway*.

So better explain what is your problem, not your solution, and perhaps we can think at something more efficient.

Comment: +1 : your right that the 256 distinct values is still going to make this very difficult not to tip to a scan.

Comment: Is not only the tipping point, is the fact that seek and range scan do not support bitwise operations. Expressing something as simple as 'bit 3 on and bi 7 off' results in a rather large number of possible ranges. The only operation that would have *some* chance is a seek on which all 8 fields (bits) are specified, resulting in  a seek on an exact byte value. Even then, with 1/256 selectivity, is a rather wide seek.

Comment: Agreed, the OP has specified all 8 values will be used per query against it so not requiring bitwise operations. The computed value option is perhaps the best to allow both, but as you say, its unlikely to work regardless.

Comment: IF all 8 bits are *Always* specified then making this 1 byte field the leading key of the clustered index can help, as it will cause a range scan on 1/256th size of the table, which is a significant IO reduction. But of course, the rest of the workload would have to be considered.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: maybe _covering_ indexes starting with bit columns can still make sense

Answer (score 3):

I would go for the one byte option being indexed, or at least a computed 1 byte column with the 8 values together incase you have the need to keep them seperate for other facilities .
(best of both worlds perhaps)

As one byte, the cardinality of the matching results for a search against all 8 values is more likely to avoid tipping points, than the 8 seperate indexes - even though those 8 indexes can be joined by the engine, I have a suspicion that cardinality may make the query tip and scan instead of seek - would have to run tests to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

One byte query will work faster. Constructing the byte to compare in memory will be much faster.

Comment: define what you mean in memory, indexing and data are read at the lowest granularity of a page regardless

Comment: @Andrew what I mean is if you execute a query with 8 separate fields (8 comparisons) instead of 1 byte with 8 bits built in memory before executing the query which will be 1 comparison.

Comment: That is an incredible micro-optimization - the larger issues of index usage and IO are orders of magnitude more important

Comment: @Alex the answer is based on the understanding of how a database query would execute and what overheads you would have while executing the query. I don't have benchmarks but its common sense and can be proven mathematically or experimentally :).

Comment: @Andrew 1 query covers that point. I think you are missing the point.